# Whitelisting ip addresses and redirecting users on WordPress login page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-login

I want to make a plugin for my own WordPress website, in which if the login page of WordPress is accessed from a specific address, then it is shown, otherwise it is redirected to homepage.

Example:

```
if(current_page == login && ip_address != xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
 redirect_to_homepage;
```

I have made a simple plugin that reads ip address of current visitor and can access current page url, but the plugin does not run on the login page. The plugin executes on all public pages like `example.com/index.php`, but not on `example.com/wp-login.php`

I assume that I should use:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'ss_check_login');
```

so that I can redirect page before headers are sent. Am I correct?

How to execute a plugin (and its code) on WordPress login page.

And I want to know what add_action to use for redirection?

I do not want to use `.htaacess`.

Comment: Which hook did you use for redirecting? Explain more and add more details otherwise your problem is not reproducible!

Comment: hi, I am not sure what add_action to use. I mean what action would be appropriate that runs my above code?

Comment: I can see that, but what is your **current** action/filter hook? Include it in your question so that we would try to debug it for you!

Comment: @Ruvee add_action('template_redirect', 'ss_check_login');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could set this up. For example, you could use `login_init` action hook. Use the following code, I've added comments for each step:

```php
add_action('login_init', 'redirecting_users');

function redirecting_users()
{
    // Getting the current page
    global $pagenow;

    // Whitelisting ip addresses in an array so that you could add more than one ip address
    $allowed_ip_addresses = array('0000000000', '111111111111');

    // Getting the current ip of the user
    $current_ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (
        'wp-login.php' == $pagenow
        &&
        !in_array($current_ip_address, $allowed_ip_addresses)
       ) 
    {
        wp_safe_redirect(site_url());
        exit;
    }
};
```

**Note:**

- Like I said in the code comments, I've used an array to whitelist the ip addresses, so that you could add more than one ip address.
- I've used `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the current ip, but there are other ways too!

Comment: thanks, I was actually writing code with admin_init hook. and found similar question at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/disable-or-redirect-wp-login-php I will try your code now.